# C# reassigning array values(down one step ex 5-4) that are within an object during a event

Tags: c#, arrays, object

Just learning C# (along with object and event programing) and the teacher didn't really show us how to get things done.

```
class Postion
{
    private int[] x_coordinate = new int[100];
    private int[] y_coordinate = new int[100];
    private double[] speed = new double[100];
    private int[] direction = new int[100];
    const int MAX_SPEED = 50;
    int counter = 0;


    public Postion()
    {
        x_coordinate[counter] = 0;
        y_coordinate[counter] = 0;
        speed[counter] = 0;
        direction[counter] = 0;
    }


    //get set methods
    public int X
    {
        get
        {
            return x_coordinate[counter];
        }
        set
        {
            x_coordinate[counter] = value;
        }
    }
```

There is one more Class between them

The values are frist assigned by a button click.

```
 Airplane newplane = new Airplane();
  private void BtnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        bool box = txtName.Text != "";
        if (box == true)
            newplane.Name = txtName.Text;
        else { }

        box = txtx.Text != "";
        if (box == true)
            newplane.PlanePostion.X = int.Parse(txtx.Text);
        else { }
```

Etc.

I can call on the array values for display for the list box.

```
 private void lsbplanes_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        placeholder = newplane.PlanePostion.Counter;
        newplane.PlanePostion.Counter = lsbplanes.SelectedIndex;
        if (newplane.PlanePostion.Counter < 0)
            newplane.PlanePostion.Counter = 0;
        else { }

        lblxshow.Text = Convert.ToString(newplane.Getx());
```

but when using a destroy button to remove an item in the list box I need to have it so the box updates with the new values when the user selects the item in the listbox.

This is what I have to try and do it so far, it sets all the ones above to 0s but does remove the the deleted one fine

```
private void BtnKill_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (lsbplanes.SelectedIndex == -1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select an item first.", "No item selected", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
        else
        {
            placeholder = lsbplanes.SelectedIndex;
            newplane.PlanePostion.Counter = lsbplanes.Items.Count;

            while (newplane.PlanePostion.Counter > placeholder)
            {
                placex = newplane.PlanePostion.X;
                placey = newplane.PlanePostion.Y;
                placespeed = newplane.Getspeed();
                placedic = newplane.Getdirection();

                newplane.PlanePostion.Counter--;

                newplane.PlanePostion.X = placex;
                newplane.PlanePostion.Y = placey;
                newplane.PlanePostion.Speed = placespeed;
                newplane.PlanePostion.Direction = placedic;

            }
            lsbplanes.Items.RemoveAt(lsbplanes.SelectedIndex);


            newplane.PlanePostion.Counter = lsbplanes.Items.Count;
        }
```

anyone can help me on this?

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what is/isn't behaving properly? i.e. what is the problem? As a side note, having 4 arrays isn't really a helpful design here - if that comes from the course it'll have to do, but a `List<Plane>` (for some `class Plane`) would be *so* much easier to grok, with each `Plane` having the 4 properties. Then removal is simply `list.RemoveAt(5)` or whatever

Comment: when using a destroy button to remove an item in the list box I need to have it so the box updates with the new values when the user selects the item in the listbox.

so far,it sets all the list items above to 0s instead of having the values passed along

Comment: @Thywolf - follow the data; it looks like  the final item (or it could be the final+1th item) is being stamped over the top of everything. But this whole "Current" property into hidden data is just so... foreign! I *suspect* the fix would be as simple as "move forwards in the list, each time capturing the values from i+1 and writing back into i", but **seriously**, the right fix here is to use a `List<T>`

Comment: @Marc - kinda what I was trying with the while loop. I don't know how i would implement the `List<t> `
a video of the error [http://www.livestream.com/thywolf/video?clipId=pla_9fe89f10-5568-4671-8fd0-618f40a9dba1&utm_source=lslibrary&utm_medium=ui-thumb] you can skip the first 2 minutes of it

Comment: `newplane.PlanePostion.Counter = placeholder;
                newplane.PlanePostion.Counter++;
                while (newplane.PlanePostion.Counter <= lsbplanes.Items.Count)
                {                    
                    placex = newplane.PlanePostion.X;
                 
                    newplane.PlanePostion.Counter--;

                    newplane.PlanePostion.X = placex;
                   
                    newplane.PlanePostion.Counter += 2;
                }`

this sets it right

Answer (score 0):

I was torn in this question, answer exactly what your problem is, or suggest that you redesign it.

@Marc is right you should be using some sort of List<Position> on your Plane object (or a ReadOnlyObservableCollection<Position>).

@Marc is also right, that the problem you are having is that you are trying to push the values down from the end of the list and overwriting them.  In these cases it is better to start from the deletion point and pull them down.

So if you have {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10} and you delete from item 5, you would have {1,2,3,4,10,10,10,10,10,10}.  The code below will let you end up with {1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,0}

```
        placeholder = lsbplanes.SelectedIndex;
        int idx = placeholder;

        while (idx < lsbplanes.Items.Count)
        {
            newplane.PlanePosition.Counter = idx+1;
            placex = newplane.PlanePostion.X;
            placey = newplane.PlanePostion.Y;
            placespeed = newplane.Getspeed();
            placedic = newplane.Getdirection();

            newplane.PlanePostion.Counter = idx;

            newplane.PlanePostion.X = placex;
            newplane.PlanePostion.Y = placey;
            newplane.PlanePostion.Speed = placespeed;
            newplane.PlanePostion.Direction = placedic;

            idx++;

        }

        // Need to zero out elements at the end
        newplant.PlanePosition.Counter = lsbplanes.Items.Count;
        /* Zeroing code goes here */

        newplane.PlanePosition.Counter = placeholder;
        lsbplanes.Items.RemoveAt(lsbplanes.SelectedIndex);
```